# POST a file with React.js

Tags: reactjs, post, spring-boot, reactjs-flux

The end user is supposed to upload through a file browser an excel file:

```js
<FloatingActionButton title="Upload excel" primary className="import-vendor"
                      containerElement="label"
                      label="Browse file">
      <input onChange={(e) => Actions.uploadXLS(e.target.files[0])} 
             type="file" 
             name="xls" 
             accept="application/vnd.ms-excel" 
             style={{ display: 'none' }}/>
      <UploadIcon/>
</FloatingActionButton>
```

Action :

```js
uploadXLS(file) {
    this.getInstance().callUploadXLS( file );
}
```

Service :

```js
callUploadXLS: {
    remote( state, data ) {
        const url = `${base}/vendor/form`;
        return $http.instance.api.post( url, data );
    },
    success: Actions.XLSUploaded,
    error: Actions.fail
}
```

This file should be sent to a POST REST endpoint built with Spring boot accepting a multipart file. The endpoint does not recognize sending the file like this

```
error: "Internal Server Error"
exception :"org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException"
message : "Current request is not a multipart request"
path : "/vendor/form"
status : 500
timestamp : 1501747384079
```

How can I post the the excel file?

Edit: I am trying now to post a list of file:

```
const arrayOfFile = [];
let i = 0;
for ( i = 0; i < files.length; i++ ) {
  const data = new FormData();
  arrayOfFile[i] = data.append( 'file', files[i] );
}
this.getInstance().callUploadXLS( arrayOfFile );
```

but data.append( 'file', files[i] ); is always returnin undifined

Comment: Can you add the action code here as well `Actions.uploadXLS`

Comment: @drinchev check the update

Comment: move `const data = new FormData();` before your `for`-loop. And provide the ajax call with `data`, not `arrayOfFile`.

Comment: I did that but same result.

Comment: let i = 0;
    const data = new FormData();
    for ( i = 0; i < files.length; i++ ) {
      data.append( 'file', files[i] );
    }
    console.log(data);
    this.getInstance().callUploadXLS( data );
console prints: 
FormData{}

Comment: You should write another question with the details around what you want to do.

Comment: @drinchev
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45545647/post-muiltiple-multipart-file-with-react

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing a file to the backend is done via `multipart/form-data` forms.

If you inspect the request that you send to the backend right now, you will see that your request does not send ( probably ) a `multipart/form-data`.

You can check for reference [What does enctype='multipart/form-data' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean) question.

Your code should look something like :

```
callUploadXLS: {
    remote( state, file ) {
                // ^ make sure that `file` here is the same target.files[0]. It should be `File` Object

      // Will turn your form to `multipart/form-data`
      var data = new FormData();
      data.append('file', file);

      const url = `${base}/vendor/form`;
      return $http.instance.api.post( url, data );

    },
    success: Actions.XLSUploaded,
    error: Actions.fail
}
```

Comment: What if I want to upload a list of files?
Check the update please and your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [good file uploader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-file-uploader) and inspect element check your network tab whether you api call that is file upload is sending proper file data as expected by the server. Test the API from [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/postman?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) if its working then it means front-end code has problem and you can compare the headers what wrong items you are sending.

Hope this debugging method will help you to recognize your mistake.

Comment: error
:
"Internal Server Error"
exception
:
"org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException"
message
:
"Current request is not a multipart request"
path
:
"/vendor/form"
status
:
500
timestamp
:
1501747384079